# Append dataframe to CSV file automatically

Tags: python, pandas, csv, twitter

I have a script which gets a range of tweets and converts these to a dataframe. I would like to run this every 2 hours using cron, and append the results to one CSV. However, I am having trouble with the appending part. This is the code I used to try it:

```
import csv   
df
with open(r'name of csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(df)
```

Only the first line of the dataframe gets appended. Does anyone know how to solve this?

Edit: Thanks everyone I solved how to do it!

This was my code:

```
df.to_csv('name', mode = 'a', header = False)
```

Comment: Untested... if you've got a DataFrame called `df`... then instead of opening the file manually etc...,  do... `df.to_csv('name of csv file', mode='a', header=None)`...

Comment: Thanks it worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can let pandas append to your CSV.

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

# create our CSV file
path = 'abc.csv'
old_data = '''\
a,b,c
1.1,1.2,1.5
2.1,2.2,2.5
'''
b = StringIO(old_data)
df = pd.read_csv(b)
df.to_csv(path, index=False)

# get a DataFrame
d = {
    'a': [0.9, 1.9, 2.9, 3.9],
    'b': [0.1, 1.2, 2.3, 3.4],
    'c': [10, 11, 12, 13],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(d)

# append DataFrame to our CSV file
with open(path, 'a') as f:
    # skip headers
    df.to_csv(f, index=False, header=False)

# show results
df = pd.read_csv(path)
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `writer.writerows(df)` rather than `writer.writerow(df)` if your `df` object stores more than one dataframes. Please refer to this [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows). Therefore, changing your code the following should help you:

```py
import csv   
df
with open(r'name of csv', 'a') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have used the `writerow` method. That would need to be in a loop.

Also, since you have a dataframe, you should probably prefer its to_csv method